# Why is my script not going up one level when using /../?

Tags: bash, scripting, path

I have the understanding that using "/../" in a file location in bash will go up one level. That's what I'm trying to do here:

```
  for box in {0..4}
  do
   for lvl in {0..24}
   do
    key="UNLOCKED_${box}_$lvl"
    plutil -key "$key" -value '1' "$appdir/../Library/Preferences/com.chillingo.cuttherope.plist" 2>&1> /dev/null
    #successCheck=$(plutil -key "$key" "/$appdir/../Library/Preferences/com.chillingo.cuttherope.plist")
    #if [ "$successCheck" -lt 1 ]; then
    # echo "Level ${box}-$lvl failed! "
    #fi
   done
  done
```

But I keep getting this error (x125):

```
Error: File not found at path /var/mobile/Applications/1E17CC78-AA6E-4FFA-B241-74A73FE3AB0E/CutTheRope.app/../Library/Preferences/com.chillingo.cuttherope.plist
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated/
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/ means start from the root of the filesystem or context, and ../ means go up one level.  /../ effectively cancels the two out.

To go up one level, try ../

EDIT:  In other words, try removing the / from the end of the variable in your path.

EDIT #2:  The best solution is to probably just remove the /../

EDIT #3:

This would work:

```
  /var/mobile/Applications/1E17CC78-AA6E-4FFA-B241-74A73FE3AB0E/CutTheRope.app/Library/../Library/Preferences/
```

And if you removed the second Library and the .. it should also work:

```
 /var/mobile/Applications/1E17CC78-AA6E-4FFA-B241-74A73FE3AB0E/CutTheRope.app/Library/Preferences/
```

Comment: So, I would do "${appdir}../Library/Preferences/plistname.plist"?

Comment: Yes :)  You are correct.  I think...  It might just be easier to just remove the .. though.

Comment: When I do ${appdir}../Library/Preferences/plistname.plist, I get: Error: File not found at path /var/mobile/Applications/1E17CC78-AA6E-4FFA-B241-74A73FE3AB0E/CutTheRope.app../Library/Preferences/com.chillingo.cuttherope.plist

Comment: cd /home/james/../james  - When I try that from my command prompt I end up in the same place as if I go to cd /home/james.  So unless appdir leads to the Library directory, you'll probably want to remove the .. altogether.  In other words, I may change my original answer ;)

Comment: It doesn't look like your appdir ends in /Library:  /var/mobile/Applications/1E17CC78-AA6E-4FFA-B241-74A73FE3AB0E/CutTheRope.app

Comment: Yeah. Library is located in 1E17CC78-AA6E-4FFA-B241-74A73FE3AB0E, hence why I need to go up a level.

Comment: According to your error message, you're looking for Library inside the CutTheRope.app directory, not the 1E17CC78-AA6E-4FFA-B241-74A73FE3AB0E directory.  I'd suggest you play with this on the command line using 'cd' for awhile so you can get a clear picture of what is happening.  Maybe also posting the folder structure will help.

Answer (score 0):

The lookup procedure is as follows:

```
inode lookup(string path) {
  inode cur = path[0] == '/' ? process->root_directory : process->current_directory;
  foreach component in split(path, '/') {
    inode next = cur.get_entry(component);
    if (next is a file && the component is the last one)
      return;
    if (next is a directory)
      cur = next;
    else
      return null;
  }
  return cur;
}
```

There is no special handling for `..`. The point is that a file can only appear as the very last component of the path. If it appears before, the `return null` path will be taken.

The actual implementation (for example in [NetBSD](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=package%3Anetbsd+%5Elookup%5C%28+file%3Akern%2Fvfs_lookup.c)) is a bit more complicated.

**Update:** I just saw that in your question `$appdir` will probably point to a directory, so the above discussion does not apply. Still, there might be some symlinks involved. When you follow a symlink and then continue with `..`, the `lookup` function continues from where the symlink points to. A small example:

```
$ ln -s somewhere/else/deep/in/the/path symlink
$ ls -l symlink/..
```

This will resolve to `somewhere/else/deep/in/the` (provided it exists). The `lookup` function will not simplify the path `symlink/..` to `.` or as another example `first/../second` will not be simplified to `second`.